# Calling a Python file with arguments form within another Python file

Tags: python

Suppose I need to run a python file, `x.py`, from within `y.py`, passing variable `z` from `y.py` to `x.py`.

How would I accomplish this? Would something like this work?

```
call(["python","x.py",z])
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Comment: Does `x.py` accept command line arguments?

Comment: You should encapsulate the functionality of `y` in a function, then `import` that function in to `x` and call it appropriately.

Comment: That will work if _call_ is subprocess.call and _z_ is a string. You need to write some code and do some experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate your code correctly.  You should have something like this:

`y.py`

```
def y_func(*args):
    # everything y does
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    y_func(*sys.argv)
```

`x.py`

```
from y import y_func
def x_func(*args):
    #do stuff
    y_result = y_func(*yargs)
    #finish x stuff
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    x_func(*sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# y.py
import os
z='argument'
os.system('Python x.py '+z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `subprocess` is better than `os.system`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-ltr"])
```

---

In your case let's say you have `a.py`:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1:]
```

and in the prompt:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["python", 'a.py', 'aaa bbb ccc'])
"['aaa bbb ccc']\n"
>>>
```